# Adding element to word with OpenXML causes error Impoossible to open the document Word?

Tags: python-2.7, ms-word, lxml, openxml, python-docx

I want to replace client address with th client address  from the database so i tried to do it with OpenXMl with the following code:

```
 xml_from_file = self.get_word_xml('modele_fichier.docx')
 xml_tree = self.get_xml_tree(xml_from_file)

 for node, text in self._itertext(xml_tree):
     if node.text=='%(client_adresse)s':
            parent=node.getparent()
            parent.remove(node)
            MY_NAMESPACES={'w': 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2007/wordml'}
            w_t=etree.Element('{%s}t' % MY_NAMESPACES['w'], nsmap=MY_NAMESPACES)
            w_cr=etree.Element('{%s}cr' % MY_NAMESPACES['w'], nsmap=MY_NAMESPACES)
            w_t.text = client_street
            parent.append(w_t)
            parent.append(w_cr)
            w_t.text = client_street2
            parent.append(w_t)
            parent.append(w_cr)
```

when i print the result of my xml i get the folowing result:

```
<w:document xmlns:wpc="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordprocessingCanvas" xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" xmlns:r="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships" xmlns:m="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/math" xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" xmlns:wp14="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordprocessingDrawing" xmlns:wp="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/wordprocessingDrawing" xmlns:w10="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:word" xmlns:w="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main" xmlns:w14="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordml" xmlns:w15="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2012/wordml" xmlns:wpg="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordprocessingGroup" xmlns:wpi="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordprocessingInk" xmlns:wne="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2006/wordml" xmlns:wps="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordprocessingShape" mc:Ignorable="w14 w15 wp14">

  <w:body>
<w:p w:rsidR="000F2E0E" w:rsidRPr="00383AED" w:rsidRDefault="00383AED" w:rsidP="00383AED">
  <w:r w:rsidRPr="00383AED">
    <w:t></w:t>
  </w:r>
  <w:r w:rsidR="00FA4935" w:rsidRPr="00FA4935">
    <w:t xmlns:w="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2007/wordml">tun2</w:t>
    <w:cr xmlns:w="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2007/wordml"/>
  </w:r>
  <w:bookmarkStart w:id="0" w:name="_GoBack"/>
  <w:bookmarkEnd w:id="0"/>
  <w:r w:rsidRPr="00383AED">
    <w:t></w:t>
  </w:r>
</w:p>
<w:sectPr w:rsidR="000F2E0E" w:rsidRPr="00383AED">
  <w:pgSz w:w="11906" w:h="16838"/>
  <w:pgMar w:top="1417" w:right="1417" w:bottom="1417" w:left="1417" w:header="708" w:footer="708" w:gutter="0"/>
  <w:cols w:space="708"/>
  <w:docGrid w:linePitch="360"/>
</w:sectPr>
</w:body>
</w:document>
```

The document is generated succefully but it is impossible to open it.
Any help please ?

Answer (score 1):

Possibly, it's because you're assigning the namespace for 2007 to the w: prefix directly in the elements. But in the top-level node the namespace assigned to the prefix w: is for a different version.